# Ignore missing pattern in Isabelle

Tags: functional-programming, isabelle, theorem-proving

For example, I would like to define a function that extracts the first element of a list. For this function, I do not care about the case when the list is empty (e.g. I can make sure that every time I use the function, I will pass a non-empty list). But Isabelle would warn that

```
Missing patterns in function definition:
extracts [] = undefined
```

How can I deal with situations like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few options available, for example:

1. `fun extracts where "extracts xs = hd xs"`
2. `definition extracts where [simp]: "extracts = hd"`
3. `fun extracts where "extracts xs = (case xs of (x # _) ⇒ x)"`
4. `fun extracts where "extracts (x # _) = x" | "extracts [] = undefined"`